# Really need to translate this CGRect code from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, position, swift, translate

I need to change the position of a `UIButton` when it is clicked (iOS). I found a tutorial that says:

```
-(IBAction) move {    
   CGRect frame = [buttonMove frame];    
   frame.origin.x = 100;    
   frame.origin.y = 10;    
   [buttonMove setFrame: frame];    
}
```

Can somebody help me translate that to Swift please? [Link to the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9xoGcaVgneI)

Comment: You should try converting it yourself, show what you tried and ask about what doesn't work properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing hard here, just the matter of the syntax

```
@IBAction func move() {
    var frame = buttonMove.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 100
    frame.origin.y = 10;
    buttonMove.frame = frame;
}
```